# Passing a function to multiple dataframes at the same time

Tags: r

I have 3 dataframes:

```
iris1<-iris[1:50, ]
iris2<-iris[51:100,]
iris3<-iris[101:150,]
```

And a simple function that takes the input of a dataframe and a column and multiplies that column by 100 and then returns the dataframe:

```
add_col<-function(df,colname)
{
df$newcol<-df [, colname]*100
return(df) 
}
```

I can then use that function on a dataframe to get the extra column added:

```
iris1<-add_col(df=iris1,colname="Sepal.Length")
```

How can I pass all the dataframes to this function rather than repeating the above 3x (1 for each dataframe?). I assume this is a problem that will use the apply family for functions but I can't work out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution, based on `purrr::map`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- c("iris1", "iris2", "iris3")

map(map(x, ~ as.symbol(.x) %>% eval),
    ~ add_col(.x, "Sepal.Length")) %>%
  set_names(x) %>%
  list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: is there a way to just pass a vector into this code rather than having to type out iris1, iris2, iris3 twice (once for the map function and then once for set_names)? For example to have code earlier on to designate the df's as iris_dfs<-c("iris1","iris2","iris3")

Comment: Yes, @Basil, see my edited solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
new_list <- lapply(list(iris1, iris2, iris3), add_col, colname = "Sepal.Length")
```

Here, you will have the three data frames as list elements and you could get them back as real data frames by e.g.:

```
iris1_new <- new_list[[1]]
```

Or you can do the following to assign the new list elements to the global environment:

```
new_names <- c("iris1_new", "iris2_new", "iris3_new")
lapply(1:length(new_names), function(x) assign(x = new_names[x], value = new_list[[x]], envir = .GlobalEnv))
```